# Bold and Italic options in a textarea Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a textarea where the user has the option to make the text within it bold or italic or both.

This is my HTML:

```
    <!-- Bold and Italic Buttons -->
    <div class="formatting-buttons">
        <i class="bold-button" (click)="toggleBoldText()" style="margin-right: 1%;">&#x42;</i>
        <i class="italic-button" (click)="toggleItalicText()">&#x49;</i>
    </div>`
```

and this is my ts:

```
toggleBoldText() {
 // Check if bold is already applied
 if (this.isBold) {
  // Remove bold by replacing the selected text
  this.responseText = this.responseText.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '');
 } else {
 // Apply bold to the selected text
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  this.responseText = this.responseText.replace(selectedText,'<strong>' + selectedText + '</strong>);
}
this.isBold = !this.isBold;
}

toggleItalicText() {
 // Check if bold is already applied
 if (this.isItalic) {
  // Remove bold by replacing the selected text
  this.responseText = this.responseText.replace('<i>', '').replace('</i>', '');
} else {
// Apply bold to the selected text
const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
this.responseText = this.responseText.replace(
 selectedText,
 '<i>' + selectedText + '</i>'
 );
}
this.isItalic = !this.isItalic;
}
```

here are all variables:

`responseText: string = '';   isBold = false;   isItalic = false;`

I have tried making those functions but the only thing they currently do is make the text wrap with  or  tags for example:

`<strong> here is text </strong> <i> here is text 2 </i>`

and that would be within the textarea

Answer (score 0):

You mention using a `<textarea>` and you cannot put other HTML tags in those, as you are discovering - but I also don't see a `<textarea>` in the code you have shown.

Here's a non-angular example, but you'll get the idea.  Instead, you can use a `<div contenteditable>`

```js
const editor = document.querySelector('#editor')

document.querySelector('#btn-bold').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  editor.innerHTML = editor.innerHTML.replace(selectedText, '<strong>' + selectedText + '</strong>');
});
```

```css
#editor{margin: 1rem 0; padding:0.5rem; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-bold">Bold Selection</button>

<div id="editor" contenteditable>This is some content you can select, click the button to make the selected portion bold!</div>
```

Comment: sorry here is my textarea:

<textarea
 [(ngModel)]="ideaText" placeholder="Write your text here ..." type="text" rows="4" style="width:100%" [attr.disabled]="loading ? true: null">
</textarea>

Comment: @Glenner13 ok, well what my answer here is trying to show you is that what you are trying to do cannot be achieved with a `<textarea>` and you need to use a `<div contenteditable>` instead